# Problem with Auto Role Function in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing an auto role function for a Discord server but it is not functioning as intended. Any info would help. Here is my code, it is being run on Python 3.7 on raspberry Pi. (Edit2: Revised the code but there still is not anything happening, I imported the DiscordUtils library to add more functions ).

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import DiscordUtils

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

description = '''Bonzi Buddy Stealer of Memes'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description=description)

role = 'level 1'
client = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Waluigi for Atari 2600"))
    
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {str(error)}")
    print(ctx.message.author)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="787454585731284992")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    """Says world"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send("world")
    print(ctx.message.author)

@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, left : int, right : int):
    """Addition"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(left + right)
    print(ctx.message.author)

@bot.command()
async def subtract(ctx, left : int, right : int):
    """Subtraction"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(left - right)
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
@bot.command()
async def multiply(ctx, left : int, right : int):
    """Multiplication"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(left * right)
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
@bot.command()
async def divide(ctx, left : int, right : int):
    """Division"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(left / right)
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
@bot.command()
async def joke(ctx):
    """Unfunny Joke"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(random.choice(jokes)) 
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
@bot.command()
async def sayuser(ctx):
    """get user name"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send("mention: " + user.mention + " name: " + user.name)
    print(ctx.message.author)

@bot.command()
async def mario(ctx):
    """RUN"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/731930062777221171/794807999096684584/video0_67.mp4")
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
@bot.command()
async def betaGif(ctx):
    """NULL"""
    user = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(random.choice(gifs))
    print(ctx.message.author)
    
#@bot.command()
#async def gif(ctx):
    #ctx.send(file=discord.File('squidward.gif'))
    
jokes = ["What do you call a Cow that can\'t give milk? An utter faliure!",
         "What do Donkeys send out near Christmas? Mule tide greetings!",
         "Who earns a living by driving his customers away? A Taxi Driver!",
         "What question can never be answered by yes? Are you asleep?",
         "Why do they call HTML hyper text? Too much Java!",
         "When is the best time to got to bed? When the bed won\'t come to you!"]

gifs = ["https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/817586768827121666/836011336437727262/image0.gif",
        "https://tenor.com/view/jontron-just-let-me-die-flex-tape-im-too-perfect-let-me-die-gif-13374794",
        "https://tenor.com/view/tf2-spy-spy-tf2-gentlemen-gif-18144778"]

bot.run(TOKEN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: What's the problem? Not working? Error?

Comment: Have you imported Intents? What is `defualtRole`? Where did you define the embed?

Comment: defualtRole is a Variable that is assigned to the role that is supposed to be assigned. I removed embed since it was not needed.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get errors but the program just doesn't carry out its function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a few errors I found: 
`embed` isn't defined in line 2
`defualtrole` must be a string or a variable which I don't see
`get` isn't defined

**This was before the edit** ^

`get` isn't defined. You probably want `discord.Utils.get` and add the `defualtRole` to the function scope so it isnt global.
What is your error right now though?

Comment: No error I rewrote some code so I am using the DiscordUtils Library though the code still won't work.

Comment: try getting the role with `member.guild.get_role("the role id")` instead of discordutils. Although `role` can be None since if it doesn't get the role it returns None. so put an if-statement that checks `if role is None`: return